# C# win forms / Audio

Tags: c#, winforms

вопрос на счёт аудио файлов и их воспроизведения. Сейчас делаю не большую игру в windows forms. Как прописывать путь к аудио ( например во время какого либо события),и где хранить этот .wav файл, чтобы при передачи .exe файла с игрой и этих .wav аудио записей проигрывался звук и не выкидывались исключения во время работы программы на другом ПК?

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем именно вопрос... все таки как/где хранить, как игрывать записи или и то и то?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно добавить звуковой файл как ресурс (Свойства -> Ресурсы) там пункт добавить существующий ресурс(вроде так).
   Пример кода:

```
     Media.SoundPlayer eventPlayer = new  Media.SoundPlayer();
  //Что - то делаем 
       eventPlayer.Stream = Properties.Resources.Event_Level;
```

Так же можно и на прямую (из любого каталога) вызывать проигрывание файла, например:

```
Media.SoundPlayer eventPlayer = new Media.SoundPlayer(locationFiles);
 eventPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Сделал через (Свойства -> Ресурсы), работает, спасибо большое

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.